# Uninstall Microsoft Edge Windows 11

Tags: windows, windows-11, microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-app

I’ve searched the whole internet and found nothing that works, I've also searched Super User  and the information is outdated.

I ask, how do I permanently uninstall Microsoft Edge from  Windows 11?

I've tried in an elevated command shell:

```
cd 'C:\Program Files (x86)'\Microsoft\Edge\Application\120.0.2210.91\Installer

.\setup.exe -uninstall -system-level -verbose-logging -force-uninstall
```

And it seems to work on the command line but once i re-check, it's still there and running just  fine.

I'm sick and tired of it constantly opening when clicking on a link (and yes, I've went  into settings and changed the default browser for all links types) and yet my system still uses  Microsoft Edge as the default browser!

Comment: @John - Edge **absolutely** can be uninstall and is fully supported by [Microsoft](https://www.neowin.net/guides/here-is-a-simple-method-to-uninstall-edge-in-windows-10-and-11/).

Comment: @John - No, it’s not. It’s fully supported in specific regions and trivial to remove outside of those regions and become they must allow it in those regions it won’t be reinstalled once removed. It also might be difficult to reinstall, you can’t ask for something to be removed then complain, it’s difficult to reinstall.

Comment: [There are also safe tools to perform the same functions](https://www.neowin.net/news/you-can-now-uninstall-microsoft-edge-using-msedgeredirect-and-its-new-europe-mode/). [Here](https://www.neowin.net/guides/here-is-a-simple-method-to-uninstall-edge-in-windows-10-and-11/) is the safe way to do it since your only taking ownership of a single file that’s used for a single purpose. I don’t have time today to answer this question but the proposed duplicate is incorrect.

Comment: @ToxicTech - [If you are running an applicable version of Windows 11 I’ll go ahead and submit an answer.](https://blogs.windows.com/windows-insider/2023/11/16/previewing-changes-in-windows-to-comply-with-the-digital-markets-act-in-the-european-economic-area/)

Answer (score 0):

Don't bother to uninstall Edge -- at the next update, it's likely to be reinstalled.

Instead, *incapacitate Edge*. Edge Webview2, and Edge updates can be blocked with a third-party tool, such as Sordum's free [Edge Blocker](https://www.sordum.org/9312/edge-blocker-v1-9/). This also allows Edge to be started for pernicious sites that *only* work in Edge, and then Edge can be turned off again.

Answer (score -1):

> So I ask, how do i permanently uninstall Microsoft Edge from Windows 11?

Uninstalling Edge if you are on Windows 10 build 19045.3757 or Windows 11 build 22631.2787 or higher is a relatively easy process. Due Microsoft compliance with new European Union regulations, if your machine is set to an applicable region, uninstalling Edge is possible. It also is permanently removed and won’t be reinstalled.

You can take control of a JSON file in the System32 folder that determines which regions are applicable. It shouldn’t be necessary to enable the feature, since the feature should be fully rolled out, so I will only include the base instructions.

> 1. Open File Explorer and go to C:\Windows\system32. Find the IntegratedServicesRegionPolicySet file, right-click it, and select Properties.
> 2. You need to take ownership of the file: go to the Security tab and click Advanced.
> 3. Click Change next to Owner.
> 4. Type Administrators in the "Enter the object name to select" box, then click Check names.
> 5. Save the changes and return to the Properties window.
> 6. Click Edit, select Administrators, and place a checkmark next to Full Control under Allow.
> 7. Save the changes, then copy the file to another folder as a backup.
> 8. Open Notepad as Administrator: press Win + R, type notepad, and press Ctrl + Shift + Enter.
> 9. Find the setting you want to enable. The option to uninstall Edge is first in the list.
> 10. Change defaultState from disabled to enabled (or vice versa).
>     Press Win + R and type regedit.
> 11. Go to Computer\HKEY_USERS.DEFAULT\Control Panel\International\Geo and check the Name value date. You need to add that value to the list of supported countries in the JSON file.
> 12. Return to Notepad and add your country name to the list of supported regions as specified in Registry Editor.
> 13. Save the changes and restart your computer.

Once you confirm, you can remove Edge, you will want to restore the original permissions of the JSON file.

It might be necessary to explicitly enable the feature, using [ViveTool](https://github.com/thebookisclosed/ViVe/releases) and running **vivetool /enable /id:44353396** and restarting your system should enable it.

Source:

- [Here is a simple method to uninstall Edge in Windows 10 and 11](https://www.neowin.net/guides/here-is-a-simple-method-to-uninstall-edge-in-windows-10-and-11/)
- [Previewing changes in Windows to comply with the Digital Markets Act in the European Economic Area](https://blogs.windows.com/windows-insider/2023/11/16/previewing-changes-in-windows-to-comply-with-the-digital-markets-act-in-the-european-economic-area/)

Comment: I would love to improve this answer, if you have feedback, I am open to addressing any problems with this answer unless of course you are just finding random contributions that I have submitted and downvoting them.