# How to stop Microsoft Edge from reappearing on my screen whenever I'm away from the computer for a bit, without affecting other programs?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge

After a recent OS update on Windows 10, Microsoft Edge is now always on my screen whenever I come back to my computer after being away from it for a few hours.

It's always on some kind of brag screen, trumpeting some new nifty feature it has.

How can I stop that from happening *in a way that other applications are not also affected*?

P.S. It just happened again. My screen is set to require a logon after a certain time of inactivity, and when I provide my password, this is the microsoft.com URL that is displayed (see photo).  I have a USB keyboard that doesn't have a screenprint button so I took a picture with my phone.

[image: Edge screen capture]

Comment: Nor happening here. Check your home page for causing this and try a different home page.

Comment: The thing is, I don't even use Edge.  It is  not my default browser. It's opening of its own accord.  There is no home page set, just a new tab.

Comment: Try Repairing and Resetting Edge.   Something may be wrong with your OS. What you describe does not happen on any of my Windows machines - real and virtual.

Comment: Another solution may be to block edge, for example by https://www.sordum.org/9312/edge-blocker-v1-9/

Comment: Since Edge (properly running) does not cause this, blocking it won't fix the issue long term.

Comment: Try to test Windows integrity by running the commands [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: 1. Check if an unwanted  add-on was installed in Edge, e.g., with Nirsoft's BrowserAddonsView, https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/web_browser_addons_view.html . 2. Consider a privacy tool such as ShutUp10, https://www.oo-software.com/en/shutup10 , which can fix some of Edge's worst "features". 3. As @hatalmasalma mentions, Edge Blocker turns Edge off, but allows use with one click.

Comment: [You could always just uninstall it.](https://superuser.com/questions/1823821/uninstall-microsoft-edge-windows-11/1823834#1823834)

Comment: @Ramhound I have run into issues in the past where a Windows update wouldn't "take" until I had upgraded Edge, so I would prefer to avoid something that draconian.

Comment: You will then have to identify the software that is causing Edge to automatically start when you log into your system.