# How do I uninstall Microsoft Edge Update application on Windows 10?

Tags: uninstall, microsoft-edge, windows-10-1809

We have a lab machine running Windows 10 Enterprise LTSC 1809 which needs to have Microsoft Edge and all its components uninstalled as it is causing issues to the main lab application called Natus Database. We have been able to uninstall Microsoft Edge but we don't know how to uninstall Microsoft Edge Update as it has the Uninstall button greyed out. The program is in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\EdgeUpdate and even if the EdgeUpdate is deleted, it comes back within a day.Is there another way to remove this program? (which by the way won't show on Control Panel Program and Features module).

Comment: You are pushing a boulder up hill and need to accommodate Window 10 / Edge and updates.

Comment: Why do you think that Edge is causing harm to any app? This doesn't seem possible - Edge is just a browser. You need to better analyze your problem, because uninstalling Edge is very unlikely to be the solution.

Comment: So when Edge (and Chrome for that matter) are installed, the Natus Database application has display issues. The vendor has requested we uninstall both and prevent updates from being pushed.

Comment: [This](https://superuser.com/questions/1823821/uninstall-microsoft-edge-windows-11/1823834#1823834) would have been applicable but you are not running a supported version of Windows 10.  Going to link to it anyways, to link the overall issue, of uninstall Edge on Windows 10.

Answer (score -1):

You could manually disable all Edge-related update services:

- Open `services.msc`.
- Double-click *Microsoft Edge Elevation Service*, i.e., *MicrosoftEdgeElevationService*, stop it, and set *Start type* to *Disabled*.
- Double-click *Microsoft Edge Update Service*, i.e., *edgeupdate*, stop it, and set *Start type* to *Disabled*.
- Double-click *MMicrosoft Edge Update Service* (yes, there are *two* services with the same name!), i.e., *edgeupdatem*, stop it, and set *Start type* to *Disabled*.

However, it might be easier to disable Edge, Edge WebView2 and Edge updates all at once using the free [Edge Blocker](https://www.sordum.org/downloads/) app from Sordum.

[image: Edge Blocker]

You can also do so using Sysinternals free [*Autoruns*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns).

[image: Autoruns Edge assets]

Of course, **after a Windows 10 update, expect that you would need to repeat that process!** Even after Edge is completely uninstalled, a Windows update can bring it back.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this

Comment: I ended up using Edge Remover: https://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/edge_remover.html